# Understanding the "const" in a function that returns a string reference

Tags: c++, reference, constants

I have this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const string & func()
{
    static string staticString = "one";
    printf("%s\n", staticString.c_str());
    return staticString;
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
    string firstString = func();
    firstString = "two";
    printf("%s\n", firstString.c_str());
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
one
two
one
```

The part that puzzles me is that if I remove `const` from `func()` the output is exactly the same. I expected it to be:

```
one
two
two
```

If I'm getting a string *reference* from `func()` (when it doesn't have the `const` keyword), why is it being reset when I call `func()` again?

Comment: `firstString` isn't a reference so it's getting copied either way.

Comment: And when you changed to reference the compiler would complain that need to be `const string&`, and don't let you changed in line firstString = "two".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string firstString = func();
```

You're copying the string returned (by reference) into `firstString`, so changes you make to `firstString` shouldn't affect the static local. If you do this:

```
const string& firstString = func();
```

you'll take a reference to it, and see that you're not allowed to modify it. If you change `func()` to return `string&` and `firstString` to be of type `string&`, then you *will* modify the string inside `func()`.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, const indicates that the reference returned can not be used to modify the string. You are never attempting to do this, since you assign the result to individual object - string - which has nothing to do with the static string declared inside your function.

To see const in play, replace the line as following:
`std::string& firstString = func();` You will see that it will not allow you to compile the programm (provided you still have const `std::string&` as a return value of your `func()`). The error would be in this line. Now, change the line to `const std::string& firstString = func();` The programm will still fail to compile, but now at different line - `firstString = "two";`

Makes sense now?